# CPU performance using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using TheadPoolExecutor that executes on a PriorityQueue. I have set a minimum pool size of 5 and max of 50. When we ran the load test, we saw like 10% jump is CPU. The thread dump shows

pool-1-thread-5" prio=3 tid=0x020f69a0 nid=0xa3 waiting on condition [0xb517f000..0xb517f970]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:118)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1841)
        at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:470)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

Wondering the prestartAllCoreThreads() that I use in ThreadPoolExecutor will have any performance issue?

TIA

Comment: Idle threads don't do anything whether you have 5 or 5000.  Creating threads has an overhead and consumes resources but once they are created they only waste memory not cpu.  BTW: Are you sure you want more threads than you have cores? (or do you have 50 free cores)

Comment: Having more threads than cores makes sense if they are IO-bound, however having too many threads can waste CPU time with an excessive number of context switches.  See http://blogs.mulesoft.org/chasing-the-bottleneck-true-story-about-fighting-thread-contention-in-your-code/ for a very interesting explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The `sun.misc.Unsafe.park` method is where the threads that are created by the ThreadPoolExecutor will wait until new messages are received.  Internally the ThreadPoolExecutor has a queue of `Runnable`s that it will farm out to waiting threads.  If your system is idle or reasonably quiet, expect to see quite a few threads waiting in this method.

If you are profiling a system, this method will often crop up as a key consumer of time.  This is expected if most of the time the threads is waiting for work to do.

Comment: Profiling typically shows CPU time...no? I mean, I agree, if you were to continuously poll the Thread's current stack, most of the real life time is likely spent waiting for new tasks in most systems.

Comment: If some threads spend most of their time  (say 80%) in park, does that mean (other than context switching) that time "isn't used" and isn't part of whats slowing the application down?